# Mongodb Lookup error in Ansible playbook

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, ansible

I am using mongoDB with ansible where I am trying to query to mongodb collection using ansible playbook.

## main.yaml(vars file where i have declared all variables)

```
source_dir_qry_res: "/home/dpatel/Desktop/query_output/"
mongodb_parameters:
    - { collection: '1.1.1.1-mx', filter: {"config.groups.interfaces.interface.name" : "xyz"} , qry_res_file: 'allconfig' }
```

In above file, 'filter' is the query run against mongodb collection. I used filter that way by referring "Mongo Lookup inside this Ansible lookup doc http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_lookups.html"

### #main_run.yaml

```
- name: query from mongodb collection
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files: 
      - 'vars/main.yml'
  tasks:
      - name: "query to db"
        query_config:
            collection: "{{ item.collection }}"
            filter: "{{ item.filter}}"
            qry_res_file: "{{ item.qry_res_file}}"
            source_dir: "{{ source_dir_qry_res }}"
        with_items: "{{ mongodb_parameters }}"
        tags: "save-query-result"
```

## query_config (custom ansible module)

```
def main():
    module = AnsibleModule(
        argument_spec=dict(
            #host=dict(required=True),
            collection=dict(required=False),
            qry_res_file=dict(required=False),
            filter = dict(required=False),
            source_dir=dict(required=True),
            logfile=dict(required=False, default=None)),
        supports_check_mode=True)
    m_args = module.params
    m_results = dict(changed=False)

    try:
        conn = pymongo.MongoClient()
        #db = conn.m_args['dtbase']
        db = conn.mydb
        coll_name = m_args['collection']
        print "Connected successfully!!!"
    except Exception as ex:
        module.fail_json(msg='mongodb connection error: %s' % ex.message)

    try:
        query = db[coll_name].find(m_args['filter'])
        if(query):
            target_json_file = m_args['source_dir']+m_args['collection'] + m_args['qry_res_file'] + ".json"
            for ele in query:
                del ele['_id']
                with open(target_json_file, 'a') as the_file:
                json.dump(ele, the_file)

    except Exception as ex:
        module.fail_json(msg="failed to get query result: %s" %ex.message)

    module.exit_json(**m_results)

from ansible.module_utils.basic import *


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

## mongo collection (mydb[1.1.1.1-mx].find())

```
{"config": { "groups": {"name": "123", "system": {"host-name": "something"}, "interfaces": {"interface": {"name": "xyz"}}}}}
```

when I run below query from mongo shell, it's working fine.

```
mydb[1.1.1.1-mx].find({"config.groups.interfaces.interface.name" : "xyz"})
```

but when I tried to run same query though the code it gaves me below error

```
$ ansible-playbook -i hosts main_run.yml
error msg:"failed to get query result: filter must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, or other type that inherits from collections.Mapping"
```

please see these screenshot for detail error message. If anyone have any idea to solve this problem please share your thoughts that would be really helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would try to set required type in your `argument_spec`

```
    argument_spec=dict(
        collection   = dict(required=False),
        qry_res_file = dict(required=False),
        filter       = dict(required=False, type='dict'),
        source_dir   = dict(required=True),
        logfile      = dict(required=False, default=None))
```

because, by default argument type is string, so you end up with your filter object converted to string (see `incovation.module_args` in your output).

Comment: Thanks @konstantin Suvorov!! it's working now. As you said just need to add "type".